# What is the place of man in Hinduism?

Tags: belief

I have read about the women place in Hinduism that

> A woman is compared to the Divine Mother 
>     (Shakti) who has given birth to all creation.

*But Now i Want to know that.
  What is the place of man in Hinduism?*

Comment: Good question! One of the meaning is .. the fact that 'woman is compared to Divine Mother Shakti' is to encourage Men to remove all lustful thoughts and think of women as their own Mothers. This does not mean that every woman is actually an Avatar of the Goddess (although in a Advaita perspective every woman and every man is equally an Avatar of Brahman :)). So extending that to all of creation, we can say that just as a Man must look upon Woman as a Divine Mother in order to avoid lustful thoughts which distract Him, the woman should look upon the Man in a similar way. All the best !!

Comment: @Sai "although in a Advaita perspective every woman and every man is equally an Avatar of Brahman". Well, technically that's not true.  According to Advaita, both Krishna's Atma and his father Vasudeva's Atma is Paramatma.  But the reason that Krishna is an avatara and Vasudeva is not is among other things the origin and nature of their gross and subtle bodies.  Advaita says that the Vasudeva inhabited a body because of past Karma and current Avidya, whereas Krishna was born into a body not because he had Karma or Avidya, but rather he was born because of the compassion of Brahman.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well to some extent what you said is true. But what I meant was that we are all equally Avatars in the sense, we are 'God in human form' just as Sri Krishna was. From a relativistic standpoint it can be said that the difference between Sri Krishna and you and me is that He knew His true Nature as Brahman all the time, whereas we 'appear' not to, which is what you call avidya. But none the less, we are who we are. So that is what I meant. But yeah your observation is right from a 'technical' perspective. :) Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Sai It is not entirely correct that the notion of all women as divine mother is concocted by a benevolent being trying to help the cause of women. It is said that brahma expressed his inability to create women and mother goddess indicated her intervention was required for the creation of woman and infused a small part of her own self in every woman created.

Comment: @moonstar2001 You are right. I was just speaking from a general (or spiritual)point of view (thus the comment began as - **one** of the meaning". If you have some valid sources you can please add an answer below. It would be helpful to the user if he returns back to the site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place of **Man** in Hinduism is as well as a **Women** place .

If A **Women** Compared to the Divine Mother **Shakti**
who has given birth to all creation,

Then a Man also compared to

the **Peerless** *Festerer* **Preserver**,

In **Srimadbhagavad** **Gita**
it has been told by **Lord Krishna** and has been explained In Sanskrit Commentary By **Sri Shankaracharya** In **ShankarBhasya** of **Shrimad Bhagwad Gita**

Here is The Main Sloka From **GITA 8:4**

> अधिभूतं क्षरो भावः पुरुषश्चाधिदैवतम्।
>
> अधियज्ञोऽहमेवात्र देहे देहभृतां वर।।8.4।।

**Translation:-**

*The which exists in the physical plane is the mutable entity, and what exists in the divine plane is the Person. O best among the embodied beings, I Myself am the entity that exists in the sacrifice in this body.*

**Explanation Of Shankaracharya:-**

> पुरुष: पूर्णम् अनेन सर्वम् इति पुरि शयनाद
>
> वा पुरुष आदित्यान्तगर्तो हिरण्यगर्भ:सर्व -
>
> प्रनिकरणानाम् अनुग्राहक: स: अधिदैवतम् |

**Translation:-**

*Purusah means the Person, derived in the sense of he by whom all things are pervaded; or, he who lies in every heart. He is Hiranyagarbha, who resides in the Sun and sustains the organs of all creatures. He is the principle of subjective existence, the entity existing in the divine plane.*

Comment: For the time being I've undeleted your answer.  But you should add details, for instance what you mean by "Peerless Festerer Preserver".  Also you should provide an English translation for any Sanskrit that you're quoting.

Comment: By the way, what you quoted isn't a verse of the Bhagavad Gita, it's a quote from Adi Shankaracharya's commentary on the Bhagavad Gita: http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-8-4/ "Purusah means the Person, derived in the sense of he by whom all things are pervaded; or, he who lies in every heart. He is Hiranyagarbha, who resides in the Sun and sustains the organs of all creatures. He is adhi-daivatam, the entity existing in the divine plane."

Comment: yea right.....,,

Comment: Adidevatam means the devta who created everything or the devta who was present before anything was created or started like before creation of this world.

Comment: yeah right.........

Comment: In my opinion, here 'Purusha' doesn't mean 'Man'. The word is from Sankhya philosophy where-in crudely it means 'Pure Consciousness'  as compared to 'Prakruti' which is inanimate 'Matter'. It has nothing to do with 'Man' and "Woman'.

Comment: @gaj where have u read it,

Comment: @gaj In Shankhya Philosophy Prakriti is the source of the world of "becoming" (change and motion) and sensation and Purusha represents true being: inactive, unchanging, and pure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samkhya

Comment: @gaj Wikipedia is not a Philosophy Book, i think.

Comment: @gaj i think you should follow the link http://www.wabashcenter.wabash.edu/syllabi/g/gier/306/sankhya.htm

Comment: @Eshan Singh The point is, vedic concept of 'Purusa' is not even close to meaning of 'Man'. So your answer is completely wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33580/discussion-between-eshan-singh-and-gaj).